# How to access a file in a static context?

Tags: java, eclipse, file

I have the following structure in my eclipse project:

[image]

I want to access the file *lito.properties* with the method *FileInputStream*.

Searching at the internet, I found this solution:

```
FileInputStream file = (FileInputStream)this.getClass()
                                            .getResourceAsStream("/files/lito.properties");
```

It seems to be the best way to do this, but what if I'm working in a static method?
It will always give this error:

> Cannot use this in a static context

So, What I have to do to access this file in a static context?

Comment: Why not just take advantage of the `ResourceBundle`? http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-read-a-properties-file-with-a-resource-bundle.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `this.getClass()` with the name of your class and `class`:

```
FileInputStream file = (FileInputStream)
    YourClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/files/lito.properties");
```

Also, try to have all the resource files in a proper *resources* folder rather than in your java src folder. This is because some compilers like maven will ignore any non.java file from sources.

Answer (score 1):

Just put your file directly in your project folder same lvl as src folder not in it though and access like this:

```
FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream("lito.properties");
```

Or if you want it in a subfolder just add folder to root project folder then put file in it.  ex:

MyProject->Data->lito.properties

```
FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream("Data/lito.properties");
```

Comment: Sorry just put it in your project folder what ever file you need in the root of your project folder and access like above or if you want to have a folder structure just add to project folder see above.